# How to get $ Value for single row for all columns in ssrs?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report:

Which has columns Name, Budget, amount
I am trying to write an expression for columns budget and amount
when Name='ABC' then add $ to budget and amount columns.

I tried currency field but it shows $ for all the other rows as well and not just ABC.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Budget and Amount columns are numeric then you should be able to set the format expression (NOT the value expression) to something like this.

```
=IIF(Fields!Name.Value  = "ABC", "c2", "n2")
```

This will set the format to "C2" (currency with 2 decimal places) for rows where name = "ABC", otherwise it will set the format to "N2" which shows the number to 2 decimal places and uses thousand separators. if you wantthe number without separators use "f2". Adjust the number to give you the decimal places you require.

Comment: Thank you Alan. Worked for me.

Comment: Thats great. Can you pleaes mark the answer as accepted. I noticed you have a few questions on SO and none have accepted ansers. It's important that you accept answers that directly answer the question you asked so that other users searching for similar issues can see questions that have been successfully answered.